# Is it possible to read parquet INT64 timestamp on hive 2.1.1?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, parquet

As i known, hive read timestamp as parquet `INT96`, but `nifi 1.10` write parquet timestamp column as `INT64`, how to read the `INT64` timestamp from parquet hive table?

```
cloudera 6.3.2
hive 2.1.1
nifi 1.10
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not for Hive 2.1.1 (on CDH 6.3.2): reading int64 timestamps fails because of a ClassCastException when converting Long to TimestampWritable, see [HIVE-21215](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21215).